# Wordpress blog clone.. wp-admin issue

Tags: wp-admin, urls, clone-site

I wanted to clone one wordpress blog I own into another domain .. I simply downloaded the root folder with all the files from Site1 and uploaded to Site2.. and created a complete MySQL script of Site1 and executed in Site2 DB.. Everything in the user side is working fine but if I got to Site2/wp-admin, its automatically redirecting to Site1/wp-admin..

Any info on where to change this admin URL settings?

Thanks and Best Regards,
Ansar

Comment: in admin-panel I think you have the site1 as domain, change it to site2. Not completely sure, but try it

Answer (score 1):

Here's 1 way to fix this. Add below inside Site2 wp-config.php:

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://Site2');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://Site2');
```

Once logged in, go to Settings > General and change WordPress address (URL), Site address (URL) to Site2. Then delete those 2 lines that you add inside wp-config.php.

Comment: if you define WP_SITEURL and WP_HOME in wp-config.php you can't change them in admin.

Answer (score 0):

The [Codex page - Changing The Site URL](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) gives you a number of different ways of changing the URL of your site.